# Can a pwm signal be provided by only one channel on one timer?

Tags: c, timer, stm32, pwm, stm32f4

I initialized PWM configuration in 4 channels on a timer, but only the last channel I set works. Does that mean only 1 channel can work at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. as many as supported by the timer. PWM  channels using the same timer will have the same frequency.